# Missing modem.bin from stock rom

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini, radio-firmware

Since I have trouble with reception on my Samsung S4 Mini, I followed [this post](https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2015/04/04/how-and-why-to-update-the-modem-slash-baseband-firmware-on-a-samsung-phone/) to upgrade my Modem/baseband Firmware. So I downloaded two firmwares from Sammobile:

I9195XXUCNK1 - Latest for Norway (Telenor)

I9195XXUCOD3 - Latest for Nordic Countries

However, in those .tar.md5-files, there were a *NON-HLOS.bin* file, but no *modem.bin*? Isn't *modem.bin* required, or is it somewhere else (in another file in the archive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Yes, for the Samsung S4 Mini LTE (i9195), the *NON-HLOS.bin* is the modem.

To flash it with Heimdall, these are the correct steps:

- Extract the NON-HLOS.bin from the tar archive
- Connect the phone and PC
- Reboot into Download Mode using (Vol Down plus Home button combi)
- In a terminal, navigate to the folder with your modem file (NON-HLOS.bin)
- Run `heimdall flash --MODEM NON-HLOS.bin --no-reboot` from a terminal
- Reboot once again into Download Mode using (Vol Down plus Home button combi)
- Run `heimdall flash --MODEM NON-HLOS.bin --no-reboot` from a terminal
- Once done, unplug then reboot device manually.

Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49395354&postcount=105

Comment: And what if there is no `modem.bin` and no `NON-HLOS.bin`? In my stock tar I see only [this](https://imgur.com/PLxMvOd)

Comment: Which file should I extract as modem?